# 155 GB in c drive used up. 50 GB used in minutes. Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, disk-space

My laptop has Windows 7 home premium. OS is installed on C drive. The C drive has some 155 GB but currently only 1.17 GB is free.
I deleted contents of my download folder and moved the contents from my desktop and my documents. this freed some 50 GB. but within minutes it was full again.
ran disk cleanup and gained some 2 GB.
i checked size of all the folders ignored large sized windows and program files and program files (x86). Was baffled when users folder said 110 GB.
went to my user folder and selected all files n checked properties it showed under 5 GB.
So if i check my user folders properties it says 110 GB but if i check properties of its content its under 5 GB.
BTW I am not using any anti virus program.
Do you guys have any idea whats going on. Is my laptop possessed or something? :P
Please help me out.

Comment: Did u empty the recycle bin?

Comment: smells fishy...why not run a scan with MSE? its free..

Comment: turn on hidden file as well as "system file" view from folder options...then go and check users folder..

Comment: Whats MSE. I have done all basic steps like turning on hidden and sys files, emptying the recycling bin etc. the fact is i am unable to see where my over 100 GB is.

Comment: MSE = Microsoft Security Essentials - antivirus software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please download the program [TreeSizeFree](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) and run it. It shows you which folders use all the space.

[image]

Are you able to locate the folder which uses most space?

Comment: Hmmmm will try but i really do not think i will be able to install anything. currently i am on a different machine will try it later today. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: there is also a ZIP file which can be xcopied to other machines without installing anything.

Comment: wow it worked. It showed the the file in my user/my user/app/local/ dir which was not visible otherwise (even after setting the show hidden and sys flies on) i deleted it n gained 110 GB.

Comment: Glad you solved your immediate problem. You may still want to take a look at SpaceSniffer (see my answer on this page for details) - in my experience you'll always be surprised to find some space hog that's taking up more space. You can likely easily find another 10-20GB you can delete.

Comment: I definitely will do that. But first I will look for a good anti virus software as I suspect it might me some virus. Do you have any idea why such a problem might happen?

Comment: @chandings nice to hear that the issue is fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

The best tool I've found for this is [SpaceSniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/index.html). It gives you a nice graphical and dynamic representation of your disk usage using "[treemaps](http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/treemap-history/)". The tool lets you zoom into specific areas to quickly find the space hogs. If you run it while you're experiencing the rapid disk consumption you describe, you can easily see the part of your disk usage that is growing. Unlike some programs, it also identifies and maps hidden and obfuscated directories that a rogue program might create.

FYI, it can also be run without installation (e.g., from a USB drive).

Here's an example screenshot from their site:

[image: SpaceSniffer Screenshot]

Comment: +1: treemaps are a far better visualization tool for this purpose than the accepted treeview answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I have unhidden all of my files. I don't have the solution yet as I haven't tried any. However I have found the folder which is creating the problem. c:\users\username\AppData\Roaming THe Roaming folder is grabbing 11 gb of my c drive.

Ok I have hopefully found the solution. In my case In roaming\adobe\common\media cache files

This folder contained 10 gb of cache files. I simply deleted them. In your case there may be some other program or if you are using adobe products then hopefully this folder will be creating the problem. The key point is that you should check up the folders in your roaming folder and hopefully you will find the "problem child". :)

Comment: I found my problem child and have stated this in one of my comments. my guess is that it was a virus in my case but i really do not know the core issue. I would suggest get treesizefree or space sniffer as stated above. they are great softwares to find hidden or unseen files.